# Can I use LESS mixins with `when` statement plus pseudo element

Tags: if-statement, less

Can I use LESS mixins with `when` statement plus pseudo element?
I want to create a Mixins. The logical is if the primary color is white, then I need to give `.userBadge:after` secondary-color.

Here is my LESS mixins, but it seems like does not work.

```
    .property-style(@primary-bgcolor, @primary-color, @secondary-bgcolor, @secondary-color) {
        .wrapper {
            background-color: @primary-bgcolor;
        }
        .userBadge:after(@primary-color, @secondary-color) when (@primary-color = "#fff")   {
                background: @secondary-color;
        }  
    }
```

Can you please help? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a few errors:

- You're missing the `@` in front of `secondary-color`
- Mixins are class-like `.x`, not arbitrary selectors. `x::after(...)` is invalid - you'd need `x(...) {&::after {...} }`
- Your `.property-style` mixin defines a mixin, but you never called that mixin
- Your `.userBadge` mixin defines a mixin, but you never called that mixin
- In this case `"#fff"` needs to be `#fff` without quotes - otherwise your color would have to be `"#fff"` instead of `#fff`! :D

Here's a working version of what you have (I'm leaving out `@secondary-bgcolor` since you didn't use it for anything) [[working demo](http://less2css.org/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22.property-style(%40primary-bgcolor%2C%20%40primary-color%2C%20%40secondary-color)%20%7B%5Cn%5Cn%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20%60.wrapper%60%20styles%5Cn%20%20%20%20.wrapper%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20background-color%3A%20%40primary-bgcolor%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7D%5Cn%5Cn%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20define%20the%20other%20mixin.%20note%20that%20we%20_could_%20use%20the%20same%20variable%20names%5Cn%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20but%20they%20are%20_new_%20variables%20-%20I've%20given%20them%20new%20names%20to%5Cn%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20help%20us%20remember%20that%20they%20won't%20automatically%20inherit%20the%20values%20of%20the%20parent%20mixin%5Cn%20%20%20%20.myOtherMixin(%40primary%2C%20%40secondary)%20when%20(%40primary%20%3D%20%23fff)%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20background%3A%20%40secondary%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7D%5Cn%5Cn%20%20%20%20.userBadge%3A%3Aafter%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20.myOtherMixin(%40primary-color%2C%20%40secondary-color)%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7D%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cn.property-style(%23ccc%2C%23fff%2C%23eee)%3B%22%7D)]

```less
.property-style(@primary-bgcolor, @primary-color, @secondary-color) {

    // `.wrapper` styles
    .wrapper {
        background-color: @primary-bgcolor;
    }

    // define the other mixin. note that we _could_ use the same variable names
    // but they are _new_ variables - I've given them new names to
    // help us remember that they won't automatically inherit the values of the parent mixin
    .myOtherMixin(@primary, @secondary) when (@primary = #fff) {
      background: @secondary
    }

    .userBadge::after {
      .myOtherMixin(@primary-color, @secondary-color)
    }
}

.property-style(#ccc,#fff,#eee); // result:
                                 // .wrapper {background: #ccc;}
                                 // .userBadge::after {background-color: #eee;}
```

However, nesting mixins can get pretty messy. This would be a little cleaner [[working demo](http://less2css.org/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22.variableColor(%40color%2C%20%40otherColor)%20when%20(%40color%20%3D%20%23fff)%20%7B%5Cn%20%20background%3A%20%40otherColor%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cn.property-style(%40primary-bgcolor%2C%20%40primary-color%2C%20%40secondary-color)%20%7B%5Cn%20%20.wrapper%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20background-color%3A%20%40primary-bgcolor%5Cn%20%20%7D%5Cn%20%20.userBadge%3A%3Aafter%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20.variableColor(%40primary-color%2C%20%40secondary-color)%5Cn%20%20%7D%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cn.property-style(%23ccc%2C%23fff%2C%23eee)%3B%22%7D)]

```less
.variableColor(@color, @otherColor) when (@color = #fff) {
  background: @otherColor
}

.property-style(@primary-bgcolor, @primary-color, @secondary-color) {
  .wrapper {
    background-color: @primary-bgcolor
  }
  .userBadge::after {
    .variableColor(@primary-color, @secondary-color)
  }
}

.property-style(#ccc,#fff,#eee); // result:
                                 // .wrapper {background: #ccc;}
                                 // .userBadge::after {background-color: #eee;}
```

Or if that variable color mixin doesn't actually need to be reusable [[working demo](http://less2css.org/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22.property-style(%40primary-bgcolor%2C%20%40primary-color%2C%20%40secondary-color)%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20.wrapper%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20background-color%3A%20%40primary-bgcolor%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7D%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cn.property-style(%40primary-bgcolor%2C%20%40primary-color%2C%20%40secondary-color)%20when%20(%40primary-color%20%3D%20%23fff)%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20.userBadge%3A%3Aafter%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20background%3A%20%40secondary-color%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7D%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cn.property-style(%23ccc%2C%23fff%2C%23eee)%3B%22%7D)]

```less
.property-style(@primary-bgcolor, @primary-color, @secondary-color) {
    .wrapper {
        background-color: @primary-bgcolor;
    }
}

.property-style(@primary-bgcolor, @primary-color, @secondary-color) when (@primary-color = #fff) {
    .userBadge::after {
      background: @secondary-color
    }
}

.property-style(#ccc,#fff,#eee); // result:
                                 // .wrapper {background: #ccc;}
                                 // .userBadge::after {background-color: #eee;}
```

But wait let's back up. The fact that you didn't call your mixin, at least in the code you've provided, makes me wonder if the whole thing really *needs* to be in one. If you don't really need to be able to do something like

```
.property-style(#ccc, #ddd, #eee);
alternate {.property-style(#aaa, #fff, #bbb)}
```

this much simpler solution (which relies on [default values](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-parametric-feature)) would do the trick [[working demo](http://less2css.org/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22%40primary-bgcolor%3A%20%23ccc%3B%5Cn%40primary-color%3A%20%23fff%3B%5Cn%40secondary-color%3A%20%23eee%3B%5Cn.badgeBg(%40check%3A%40primary-color%2C%20%40ifPasses%3A%40secondary-color)%20when%20(%40primary-color%20%3D%20%23fff)%20%7B%5Cn%20%20background%3A%20%40secondary-color%5Cn%7D%5Cn.wrapper%20%7B%5Cn%20%20background-color%3A%20%40primary-bgcolor%5Cn%7D%5Cn.userBadge%3A%3Aafter%20%7B%5Cn%20%20.badgeBg%5Cn%7D%22%7D)]

```less
@primary-bgcolor: #ccc;
@primary-color: #fff;
@secondary-color: #eee;
.badgeBg(@check: @primary-color, @ifPasses: @secondary-color) when (@primary-color = #fff) {
  background: @secondary-color
}
.wrapper {
  background-color: @primary-bgcolor
}
.userBadge::after {
  .badgeBg
}
/*
   result:
   .wrapper {background: #ccc;}
   .userBadge::after {background-color: #eee;}
*/
```

Bonus: just for kicks, here's a different approach you could take. It's *definitely* overkill for what you've shown here, but you might find it an interesting thing to study. It uses [default values](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-parametric-feature) and [property interpolation](http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature-properties), and it makes the color in the "if" a dynamic part of the theme. [[working demo](http://less2css.org/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22.propertyValueCondition(%40property%2C%20%40value%2C%20%40check%3A%20pass%2C%20%40guard%3A%20pass)%20when%20(%40check%20%3D%20%40guard)%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%40%7Bproperty%7D%3A%20%40value%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cn.theme(%40color1%2C%20%40color2%2C%20%40color3%2C%20%40color4%3A%23fff)%20%7B%5Cn%20%20.wrapper%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20.propertyValueCondition(background-color%2C%20%40color1)%5Cn%20%20%7D%5Cn%20%20.userBadge%3A%3Aafter%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20.propertyValueCondition(background%2C%20%40color3%2C%20%40color2%2C%20%40color4)%5Cn%20%20%7D%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cn.theme(%23ccc%2C%20%23ddd%2C%20%23eee)%3B%5Cn%5Cnalternate%20%7B%5Cn%20%20.theme(%23bbb%2C%20%23aaa%2C%20%23eee%2C%20%23aaa)%5Cn%7D%22%7D)]

```less
.propertyValueCondition(@property, @value, @check: pass, @guard: pass) when (@check = @guard) {
  @{property}: @value
}

.theme(@color1, @color2, @color3, @color4:#fff) {
  .wrapper {
    .propertyValueCondition(background-color, @color1)
  }
  .userBadge::after {
    .propertyValueCondition(background, @color3, @color2, @color4)
  }
}

.theme(#ccc, #ddd, #eee);

alternate {
  .theme(#bbb, #aaa, #eee, #aaa)
}

/*
  result:
  .wrapper {background-color: #ccc;}
  alternate .wrapper {background-color: #bbb;}
  alternate .userBadge::after {background: #eee;}
*/
```

Comment: Henry, thank you so much for your answer, it is really helpful and super details.

Comment: The Bonus method is awesome, can you please tell me what does @check: pass means here? I have searched online, and did not find the answer, thank you again.

Comment: You're welcome, glad it helped! The words "check", "guard", and "pass" are arbitrary here. In `@x: y`, `y` is the default value for `@x` (follow the "default values" link above:). I chose those words because a `when` condition in LESS is called a _guard_, and we're _checking_ the real condition against the guard. Because the guard passes when `@check = @guard`, I chose to make the passing value `pass`. Something more abstract like `...@x: 1, @y: 1) when (@x = @y)` would work the same